# Error occuring while executing c file developed using lex and yacc tools

Tags: c, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I am trying to design a mini c compiler using lex and yacc.So when i compile this using an   input c file it shows that c file has syntax error in it even though the c file doesnt have any error.

LEX FILE (c.l)

```
   %{
   #include"y.tab.h"
   int line=0;
   %}

   alpha [a-zA-Z]
   digit [0-9]

   %%
   [ \t]        ;
   [ \n]   {line++;}
    int        { return INT;}
   float    {return FLOAT; }
   char     {return CHAR;}
   void     {return VOID;}
   double   {return DOUBLE;}
   for  {return FOR;}
   while    {return WHILE;}
   if   {return IF;}
   else {return ELSE;}
   printf {return PRINTF;}
   struct   {return STRUCT;}
   ^"#include ".+ ;
   {digit}+ { return NUM;}
   {alpha}({alpha}|{digit})* {return ID;}
   "<="    {return LE;}
   ">="    {return GE;}
   "=="    {return EQ;}
   "!="    {return NE;}
   ">"  {return GT;}
   "<"  {return LT;}
   "."     {return DOT;}
   \/\/.* ;
   \/\*(.*\n)*.*\*\/ ;
   .       return yytext[0];
   %%
```

YACC FILE (c.y):

```
     %{
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>


      extern FILE *fp;

      %}

      %token INT FLOAT CHAR DOUBLE VOID
      %token FOR WHILE 
      %token IF ELSE PRINTF 
      %token STRUCT 
      %token NUM ID
      %token INCLUDE
      %token DOT

      %right '='
      %left AND OR
      %left '<' '>' LE GE EQ NE LT GT
      %%

      start:    Function 
 | Declaration
;

    /* Declaration block */
    Declaration: Type Assignment ';' 
| Assignment ';'    
| FunctionCall ';'  
| ArrayUsage ';'    
| Type ArrayUsage ';'   
| StructStmt ';'    
| error 
;

     /* Assignment block */
     Assignment: ID '=' Assignment
| ID '=' FunctionCall
| ID '=' ArrayUsage
| ArrayUsage '=' Assignment
| ID ',' Assignment
| NUM ',' Assignment
| ID '+' Assignment
| ID '-' Assignment
| ID '*' Assignment
| ID '/' Assignment 
| NUM '+' Assignment
| NUM '-' Assignment
| NUM '*' Assignment
| NUM '/' Assignment
| '\'' Assignment '\''  
| '(' Assignment ')'
| '-' '(' Assignment ')'
| '-' NUM
| '-' ID
|   NUM
|   ID
;

    /* Function Call Block */
    FunctionCall : ID'('')'
| ID'('Assignment')'
;

     /* Array Usage */
     ArrayUsage : ID'['Assignment']'
;

    /* Function block */
    Function: Type ID '(' ArgListOpt ')' CompoundStmt 
;
    ArgListOpt: ArgList
|
;
    ArgList:  ArgList ',' Arg
| Arg
;
    Arg:    Type ID
;
    CompoundStmt:   '{' StmtList '}'
;
    StmtList:   StmtList Stmt
|
;
    Stmt:   WhileStmt
| Declaration
| ForStmt
| IfStmt
| PrintFunc
| ';'
;

    /* Type Identifier block */
    Type:   INT 
| FLOAT
| CHAR
| DOUBLE
| VOID 
;

    /* Loop Blocks */ 
    WhileStmt: WHILE '(' Expr ')' Stmt  
| WHILE '(' Expr ')' CompoundStmt 
;

    /* For Block */
   ForStmt: FOR '(' Expr ';' Expr ';' Expr ')' Stmt 
   | FOR '(' Expr ';' Expr ';' Expr ')' CompoundStmt 
   | FOR '(' Expr ')' Stmt 
   | FOR '(' Expr ')' CompoundStmt 
;

   /* IfStmt Block */
    IfStmt : IF '(' Expr ')' 
    Stmt 
;

    /* Struct Statement */
    StructStmt : STRUCT ID '{' Type Assignment '}'  
;

     /* Print Function */
     PrintFunc : PRINTF '(' Expr ')' ';'
;

    /*Expression Block*/
    Expr:   
| Expr LE Expr 
| Expr GE Expr
| Expr NE Expr
| Expr EQ Expr
| Expr GT Expr
| Expr LT Expr
| Assignment
| ArrayUsage
;
    %%

    int count=0;
    #include"lex.yy.c"
    #include<ctype.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    { 
yyin=fopen(argv[1], "r");

     if(!yyparse())
    printf("\nParsing complete\n");
else
    printf("\nParsing failed\n");

fclose(yyin);
   return 0;
   }

   yyerror(char *s) {
printf("%d : %s %s\n", line, s, yytext );
   }
```

C File(add.c)

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main()
   {
   int c;
   int a=10;
   int b=10; 
   c=a+b;
   printf("the value of c is %d",c);
   return 0;
   }
```

The compilation steps are:

```
    $ lex c.l
$ yacc c.y
$ gcc y.tab.c -ll -ly 
$ ./a.out add.c
```

The output is:

```
       8 : syntax error "
       Parsing complete
```

So the question why this problem occuring in the code ?Any changes to be done to code so that it works properly.I have no idea where the problem is occuring so i have posted the whole lex and yacc code...Any suggestions would be helpful..thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure about `[ \n]   {line++;}` which increments line for spaces?

Comment: i am sure abt it...Do u want me to rethink on that line ???

Answer (score 1):

Your lex pattern for `#include` requires a trailing space which you do not have in your C source file.

Comment: So where should i modify the code so that it would run  smoothly???it would be more helpful for me if u suggest it...thanks

Comment: either fix your C example code you are trying to parse (add the missing space character) or allow `#include` without a trailing space in your lex pattern.

Comment: I'm sorry - SO's purpose is not to guide the hands of those that have no clue at all, it is to enable people to help themselves. This is what I tried.

If you would have written this code yourself (or at least read it to gain knowledge on how its supposed to work), you'd most likely know what I'm talking about. Since you don't, I'm afraid I must assume you're just copying someone elses homework trying to fix it. I refuse.

Comment: Hey thanks..i got what u said and i fixed it up successfully....sorry for incovniance caused to u...

Comment: But i encountered another error after i fixed the previous error..The error is like 8 : syntax error "
                  Parsing error.Is the error similar to the previous one ??

Comment: then you should probably look at line 8 of your program to see what's there causing the error. It's pretty obvious, honestly.